# How do I install NTP server on Windows and NTP client on Debian and configure them both?

Tags: ntp

I have configured an NTP server on my Windows, including the registry edits, services edits, and firewall. I started the time service too. I connected a Debian system to the same network and configured it as NTP client (adding the IP config of server in the configuration file of client).

It shows the server upon the

```
ntpq -p
```

command but doesn't synchronise to its time. What did I do wrong?

I even did the same with `chrony` later on, but it showed the same (i.e. `^?` next to the server name).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What do the `stratum` and `reach` fields in the outputs of `ntpq -p` or `chronyc sources` say? If `reach` is 0, the client is not getting responses from the configured server at all. If `reach` increases over time all the way to 377, then the client is getting answers, but if `stratum` is 15 it would indicate the Windows NTP server does not consider itself really reliable enough for synchronization. You might want to ask in [SuperUser.SE](https://superuser.com/) if the problem seems to be on the Windows side; it would be considered off-topic here in Unix&Linux.SE.